# keyboard short-cut or add-on to toggle full-screen message?

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

My thunderbird screen has three panels:  The bottom half shows the message.  The top half is splitted into two panels:  A small one on the left that shows the folders, and on the right it shows the messages in the highlighted folder.  I have not installed any themes/add-on to alter this setup (as far as I know).

Using the function key F8 I can toggle on/off the bottom panel, letting the thread screen on the top right to extend all the way down.  Question:  Is there a way (function key or add-on) to toggle on/off the thread screen, i.e. letting the individual message taking up the whole screen?  Of course clicking on the individual message would do that, but I'd like to be do this by keyboard-toggle.

THANKS!